# iOS - How do I convert float time to real time (hh:mm)

Tags: ios, time

I'm calculating the average travel time from one point to another by using the following calculation:

```
    float tSpeed = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", speed] floatValue];
    float duration = totDistance/tSpeed;

    tripDuration_Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", duration];
```

speed is in miles per hour so the output is in hours.

This gives me a float value for the time, I need to convert it to time (hh:mm).

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of duration? Is it seconds? We will need more details to help you.

Comment: duration = miles/mph . . . So duration would be a float representation of hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 hour is 60 minutes so:

```
NSInteger hours = duration; // 2.5 -> 2
NSInteger minutes = ( duration - hours ) * 60; // ( 2.5 - 2 ) * 60

tripDuration_Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", hours, minutes];
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you would like to do the conversion to time like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844367/converting-an-float-to-nsdate) example but before you need to get the integer values from float. 
Fot this you can use modulo to sparate things before and after comma.